# Is the stream table from the REST API incomplete?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, stream, facebook-fql

I'm trying to get all my wall information (status, photo tags, friends' posts, etc.) with the [stream table](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/stream.get/).

But when I try to do that, a lot of information which is on my wall doesn't appear in the stream response.

For example, I can't get my December status.

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 1):

From my experience, the `stream` table is incomplete. Using FQL to query the full table results in missing entries. A workaround is to query to original tables of the entries, e.g. the `status` table:

```
SELECT uid, status_id, time, source, message FROM status WHERE uid = me()
```

This is more complete. Obviously, you would have to query the `photo` table and others in parallel. In order to not loose too much time, you can batch the queries.

The `stream` table, however, seems to be fine for posts originating from friends.

A downside - apart from the multiple queries - is that the other tables don't have additional meta information about likes or comments, so these need to be retrieved in a second step then.